# overwrite function defined in external file and prevent execution in that file

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an external js file which have a method and after that it is called. Is it possible to overwrite that method and set some new code to function and than execute it?

```
xyz.myFunc = function(){
  console.log('myFunc executed');
};

xyz.myFunc();

xyz.myFunc = function(){
   console.log('myFunc overwrite');
};
```

I want the message "myFunc Overwrite". is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible (if function is called in the same external file right after it's defined).